# How to convert my data format to one accepted by ML's ALS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this problem time to time and I end up using `RDD`s to solve it, and I was wondering if it is possible to achieve it with `Spark 2.0`. The way how products' scores  is normally stored is (`userid`, `product1`, ... , `productn`). However, `ALS` instantiation requires you to set the user column, the item column and the rating column. So, is there any way to achieve this transformations using `DataFrames` transformations and/or SQL sentences?

To illustrate:
Source `DataFrame`:

```
+---+-----------------+------------------+
| id|         product1|          product2|
+---+-----------------+------------------+
|  2|4.285714285714286| 4.785714285714286|
|  3|              5.0|               5.0|
|  4|3.857142857142857|3.2142857142857144|
|  5|3.142857142857143|1.5714285714285714|
+---+-----------------+------------------+
```

Resulting `DataFrame`:

```
+------+---------+------------------+
|userid|productid|             score|
+------+---------+------------------+
|   2.0|      2.0| 4.785714285714286|
|   2.0|      1.0| 4.285714285714286|
|   3.0|      1.0|               5.0|
|   3.0|      2.0|               5.0|
+------+---------+------------------+
```

Comment: Alberto what you are asking isn't very clear. Can you illustrate it with an example ?

Comment: have you tried zipping and exploding ? You can assemble all the productX into one vector/array and explode it (without having the need to zip actually - scratch this, you eventually need some kind of a index)

Comment: You are still looking for an answer to this question ?

Comment: @eliasah, Yes it'd be great to know

Comment: Did you try the approach that I have suggested ?

Comment: @eliasah I wanted to use plain sql.